# Failed to resolve: com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:27.0.2

Tags: java, android

hi devs i'm having an issue with my Build Gradle here when i'm trying to excute the app i got these errors

```
Error:(114, 22) Failed to resolve: com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:27.0.2
Error:(115, 22) Failed to resolve: com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:27.0.2
```

my buildgradle is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 27
  buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
  flavorDimensions "1"
  lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds true
    lintConfig file("lint.xml")

  }


  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }

  signingConfigs{
    release{
      keyAlias 'your app name'
      keyPassword 'key password'
      storeFile file('location of your key file')
      storePassword 'your keystore password'
    }
  }

  productFlavors {
    madani {
      applicationId "com.herocode.quranreaderandroid"
    }


  }

  buildTypes {
    beta {
      minifyEnabled true
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard.cfg'
      signingConfig signingConfigs.release
      versionNameSuffix "-beta"
      if (project.hasProperty('disableCrashlytics')) {
        ext.enableCrashlytics = false
      }
    }

    debug {
      ext.enableCrashlytics = false
      applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
      versionNameSuffix "-debug"
    }

    release {
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard.cfg'
      signingConfig signingConfigs.release
      if (project.hasProperty('disableCrashlytics')) {
        ext.enableCrashlytics = false
      }
    }
  }

  applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    resValue "string", "authority", applicationId + '.data.QuranDataProvider'
    resValue "string", "file_authority", applicationId + '.fileprovider'
    if (applicationId.endsWith("debug")) {
      mergedFlavor.manifestPlaceholders = [app_debug_label: "Quran " + flavorName.capitalize()]
    }
  }

  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }

  testOptions.unitTests.all {
    testLogging {
      events 'passed', 'skipped', 'failed', 'standardOut', 'standardError'
      outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
      showStandardStreams true
      exceptionFormat "full"
    }
  }
}

ext {
  supportLibVersion = '27.0.2'
  espressoVersion = '2.2.2'
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
  compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.4'
  compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
  annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.8'
  compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.8'
  compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.7.0'
  compile 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.3.1'
  compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.5.0'
  compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
  debugCompile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.4.1'
  debugCompile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.4.1'
  debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5'
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  testCompile 'com.google.truth:truth:0.30'
  testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
  testCompile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:3.5.0'
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:27.0.2'
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:27.0.2'
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2'
  compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.6@aar') {
    transitive = true
  }
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
}
```

Project build is like

```js
buildscript {
  repositories {
    google()
    maven {
      url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.22.1'
    classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.4.0'
    classpath 'me.tatarka.retrolambda.projectlombok:lombok.ast:0.2.3.a2'
  }

  // Exclude the version that the android plugin depends on.
  configurations.classpath.exclude group: 'com.android.tools.external.lombok'
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    google()
    maven {
      url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right dependencies are:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.0.1'
```

Check this [doumentation](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/setup.html#set-instrumentation-runner)